# How to read cells of a connect object in visio

Tags: vba, visio

I was trying to read the BeginX, BeginY, EndX and EndY cells from all the connect object in a page, so that I could record which point from a shape is connected to which connect.

what confuses me is that the CellsU and CellsSRC seems to be not working with connect object, even it is suggested in office docs for like EndX cell. What shall I use if I want to read and save some cells from a connect object then?

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you're looking for if you explore the objects returned from the connects() method on the connect object.  Each object represents the connections made on each end of the connector and can lead you to the data in the shape object that has the coordinate information.

```
$c.Connects()


Application        : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.ApplicationClass
Stat               : 0
FromSheet          : System.__ComObject
ToSheet            : System.__ComObject
FromCell           : System.__ComObject
ToCell             : System.__ComObject
FromPart           : 9
ToPart             : 3
ObjectType         : 8
Index16            : 1
Document           : System.__ComObject
Index              : 1
ContainingPageID   : 0
ContainingMasterID : -1

Application        : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.ApplicationClass
Stat               : 0
FromSheet          : System.__ComObject
ToSheet            : System.__ComObject
FromCell           : System.__ComObject
ToCell             : System.__ComObject
FromPart           : 12
ToPart             : 3
ObjectType         : 8
Index16            : 2
Document           : System.__ComObject
Index              : 2
ContainingPageID   : 0
ContainingMasterID : -1
```